# Prime Number Verifier Code Blocks resturns me converting problems in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, primes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (isPrimeNumber(6))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is prime number");  
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not prime number");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
 

        private static bool isPrimeNumber(int number)
        {
            bool result = true;
            for (int i = 0; number - 1; i++)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    result = false;
                    i = number;
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
```

hey! there is a problem in my code blocks about prime number verifying. this program returns me that in for loop: cannot convert type "int" to "bool". how can i fix it? what's my wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *logical error*, look

```
 //typo: should be i < number - 1 instead of number - 1
 for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++)
 {
     if (number % i == 0) // <- always true, when i == 1
     {
         result = false;  // <- result == false whenever number >= 2 
         i = number;
     }
 }
```

whenever `i == 1` then `number % i == 0` and you have `result = false`.
Let's implement `isPrimeNumber` from scratch:

```
 private static bool isPrimeNumber(int number) {
   // 0, 1 and negative numbers are not prime
   if (number <= 1)
     return false;

   // we have just one even prime number, it's 2 
   if (number % 2 == 0)
     return number == 2;  

   // if we have a non-trivial divisors, the minimal one
   // is at most Sqrt(number)
   // (int) (...+1) - to be on the safe side in case of rounding errors
   int maxDivisor = (int)(Math.Sqrt(number) + 1);

   // Now we check divisor = 3, 5, 7, ..., maxDivisor
   for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= maxDivisor; divisor += 2)
     if (number % divisor == 0)
       return false;

   // All tests passed, number is prime
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed suggestion but it's complicating for me theese days because I've just started coding. But I'll be back with more experience here to check your code to improve myself.

Answer (score 2):

`for (int i = 0; number - 1; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)`  The `number - 1` is not a boolean expression.

```
private static bool isPrimeNumber(int number)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            result = false;
            i = number;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

i fixed it `for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)` should be `for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)`

Comment: yeah it works at least there is a output i can see rn but now this program returns "This is prime number" for each number what i inputted.

Comment: I didn't check if the results are right, only syntactical ;-)

Comment: You're right. I noticed there's another problem after applied your suggestions in my code blocks. Thanks for all :):)